# Need help to avoid type casting

Tags: java, generics

I need help in refactoring the following piece of code . There are 2 main problems that I want to fix in this code 
1. Unsafe type casting in Rule1 implementation
2. Implementation of too many interfaces

```
  public interface Rule {
     public void execute(DataProvider dataProvider);
  }

  public interface DataProvider {
     // No common functions as of now 
  }

  public interface Rule1dataProvider extends DataProvider {
     // Functions required by Rule1
  }

  public class Rule1 implements Rule {
     public void execute(DataProvider dataProvider) {
       ADataProvider rule1DataProvider = <ADataProvider>dataProvider;
       // Other logic 
    }
  }

 public class EntityADataProvider implements Rule1DataProvider, Rule2DataProvider... {
    // Overrides functions of Rule 1 and Rule2 
 }
```

I was trying to use generics here, but could not figure out the right way to use them in order to eliminate the type casting

Comment: What's wrong with type casting?

Comment: @HotLicks it can be error prone

Comment: @SilviuBurcea - Life is error prone.  You can't realistically have OO programming without type casting.

Comment: @HotLicks I agree, but it doesn't mean you shouldn't try hard to avoid casting.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea - So, how do you avoid it?  Generics don't avoid it, they just conceal it in a blizzard of unintelligible muck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make Rule generic:

```
public interface Rule<T extends DataProvider> {
    public void execute(T dataProvider);
}
```

And then

```
public class Rule1 implements Rule<Rule1dataProvider> {
    @Override
    public void execute(Rule1dataProvider dataProvider) {            
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this , but could not figure out a good way to get the rule1DataProvider instance from my EntityADataProvider. How do I do that ? I need this because, rule1 can be accessed by different entities , say EntityA and EntityB. In that case I should somehow derive Rule1DataPRovider from the entities respective data providers

Comment: EntityADataProvider implements Rule1DataProvider, so it *is a* Rule1DataProvider already. You can pass it to `rule1.execute()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Plese help me this followup question as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168231/collection-for-generic-trpes

Comment: Note that that doesn't avoid type casting.  It just conceals it.