# Collection for Generic types

Tags: java, generics, collections

How can I represent the generic types in a single collection?

```java
public interface Rule<T> {
  String execute(T dataProvider);
}

public interface DataProvider {
   // No common functions as of now
}

public class RulesExecutor {
     private Map<String, List<Rule>> documentToRuleListMap;
    public RulesExecutor(Map<String, List<Rule>> documentToRuleListMap) {
        this.documentToRuleListMap = documentToRuleListMap;
    }

    public executeRules(DataProvider dataProvider, String document) {
      // some logic here 
    }
}
```

Is it possible to store a map as shown in `RulesExecutor` sconstructor?

If not, what is the correct data structure to store this info in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to store a map as shown in RulesExecutor sconstructor ? If not, what is the right data structure to store this info ?

Sure:

```
public interface Rule<T> {
  String execute(T dataProvider)
}


public interface DataProvider {

}


class RulesExecutor<T extends DataProvider> {

   public RulesExecutor(Map<String, List<Rule<T>>> documentToRuleListMap) {
   }

   public void executeRules(T dataProvider) {
     // some logic here 
   };
}
```

---

Please note that your posted code will not compile due to careless mistakes:

```
public interface Rule<T> {
  String execute(T dataProvider) // *** missing semicolon
}


public interface DataProvider {

}

public class RulesExecutor() { // *** class declarations have no parenthesis
```

Please be more careful when posting code and make sure to post *real* code, not *sort-of*, *kind-of* code. It makes it easier to understand your problem and help when you do.

Comment: If `executeRules` is going to apply the rules to the `DataProvider`, then the types need to be tighter. Probably the bound on `RulesExecutor` wants to be `<T extends DataProvider>`, and the `dataProvider` parameter to `executeRules` wants to have type `T`.

Comment: This way, my RulesExecutor would become specific to a particular rule. However , my idea of the rulesexecutor here is :                                                      1. Store the Document to RuleListMapping                                    2. To execute the list of rules corresponding to a document, when passed the document as input

Comment: @user1269701: Any one instance of a `RulesExecutor` would be specific to a single subclass of `DataProvider`, but it could use any number of different `Rule` implementations. Do you want the map to contain different kinds of `Rule`s for different kinds of `DataProvider`? If so, you may need to use a 'typesafe heterogeneous container'.

Comment: Thanks @TomAnderson. "Typesafe Hetergoneous container" seems to be the right choice for me.